# LibreOffice KDE plugin install error on 5.14.0-kali4-amd64

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, dependencies, libreoffice

I am trying to follow this tutorial to make my libreOffice look pretty: https://www.debugpoint.com/2016/08/quick-tip-change-the-default-libreoffice-look-and-feel/

however when I run `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style*`, I get the following error:

```
 libreoffice-common : Breaks: libreoffice-style-tango but 1:6.1.5-3+deb10u7 is to be installed
                      Recommends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-tango : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.1.5-3+deb10u7) but 1:7.2.2-1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Let me know if you need any other information!!

Comment: you're trying to use Kali linux as everyday office platform. Definitely not the right tool for that! It's actively discouraged, by [Kali themselves!](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

Just skip installing Tango theme and move on with others. You can skip installing a package by adding its name with a minus sign like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style* libreoffice-style-tango-
```

But, please, consider that no one should be using Kali Linux just to make it look pretty and if you have such question you shouldn't be using it at all: [Should I Use Kali Linux?](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/)